How to make mansory elements responsive yet take up all available space?
I am using mansory.js to layout my images and their details ( all in a div class="main-section"), They all are contained in a div class="main", The problem I am facing is due to how the elements widths is being calculated, If I say columnWidth:300 It works fine, but when I resize the window only below 300, ( like I expand the window about 150px wider,) the layout stays the same leaving 150px blank on the right hand side, I want the column width to be dynamic so that the width of the items adjusts and increases so that they all add up to 100% of the container,
I tried using a function for it, like to calculate the width but it acts weirdly, and stacks all images on top of each other, ( kind of, I don't get it it just gets messed up)
This JavaScript code, adds those white spaces on the right hand side,
var elem = document.getElementById('main');
var msnry = new Masonry(elem, {
    itemSelector: '.main-section',
    columnWidth: 300,
    isFitWidth:true,
    percentPosition: true,
    gutter: 16 // Spacing between items
});



document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    setTimeout(function() {
        msnry.layout();
    }, 350); 
});

window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        msnry.layout();
    }, 350); 
});

This code does that jumbling of the items and messes up everything
....snry = new Masonry(elem, {
    itemSelector: '.main-section',
    columnWidth: function() {
        var elem = document.getElementById('main');
        var containerWidth = elem.offsetWidth;
        var numColumns = Math.floor(containerWidth / 300); 
        console.log( containerWidth / numColumns); 
        return 300;
    },
    isFitWidth:true,
    percent.....

[as you can see I tried debugging using console log and just returning 300, but it doesn't work, and displays nothing in console]
I attached the jumbled up image and the white space image with it too
white space on right
Weird image layout
Also here's the CSS for container
#main-container{//this covers the main
    width: calc(100% - 160px);
    margin:0px 80px;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
#main{
    width: 100%;
}
.main-section{
    width: 300px;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    border-radius: 16px;
}


maybe you should share the html you are using... I say it because you have the css rule targeting the .main-section that looks like an item of the masonry layout.. set like that it's behaving as expected where each column of the layout has 300px width. Any "weird" white space remaining before the end of the viewport should be something <300px... and if you resize the viewport below the width of the column width, it will just overflow.

Is Masonry() a custom constructor or are you using https://masonry.desandro.com/ ?

by the way the attempt of setting the columnWidth with a function instead of using a number it's totally wrong. It doesn't make any difference what the function is going to return, it won't be executed if you don't make it an IIFE expression like function (){/*...*/}() .. and by the way it will be evaluated only once when the object gets created .. not again when invoking .layout(). For reference I used the js available in the cdn here https://cdnjs.com/libraries/masonry (masonry.desandro.com)

if it is only for image and have them drawn columns by columns, css column might be enough : here a simple responsive example . you only need to set a width https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/zYVXLMr  You may use clamp() to set a min-width, average width according to the screen and a max-width  (example sets width to  min 250px, 30vw and max 400px )  no mediaquerie nor js , the browser does the job by himself.
